# Softlayer Object Storage/Swift Copy Forbidden

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure, object-storage

I am trying to copy some objects from one account to another account using the [Swift Copy API](http://developer.openstack.org/api-ref/object-storage/index.html?expanded=copy-object-detail#objects). However, I am getting 403 Forbidden response.

From the [Swift codebase](https://github.com/openstack/swift/blob/a768563bd8f099452d289a7ed617489bc5f13733/swift/common/middleware/copy.py#L72-L101):

> Objects can also be copied from one account to another account if the user has the **necessary permissions** (i.e. permission to read from container
>   in source account and permission to write to container in destination account).

I believe the reason for the 403  response is because the `X-Auth-Token` generated when [Authenticating to the Object Storage](https://sldn.softlayer.com/blog/waelriac/managing-softlayer-object-storage-through-rest-apis) is tied to a specific account, as the format for
`X-Auth-User` is `<ACCOUNT>:<USERID>`

Is it possible to generate a `X-Auth-Token` that has permission to read/write from multiple accounts on Softlayer?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the short anwer is no, the permissions are only for the owner account and the users of that account on softlayer. If you wanna copy the data you need to make your own code which donload the file from an account and then upload it to the another account.

Regards